# AngularJS Passing data from view to controller using Laravel PHP call

Tags: javascript, php, angular, laravel

I want to send some data to the simplecontroller, this data is called from the server by a Laravel or a PHP call. I want to pass it easily like this ng.user.name directive is doing.

```
<div ng-controller="simplecontroller" id="simplecontroller">
<a href="#" "ng-name={{$company->name}}" "ng-id={{$company->id}}">{{$company->name}}</a>
```

My controller will use the name and id

```
app.controller('simplecontroller', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name = ng-name // or I could call {{$company->name}} here?
    id = ng-id
  };
```

Any way to achieve this functionality? Sorry, but I am SUPER NEW to Angular JS. Please point me to the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of confusion in your code. You need to learn angularjs better...

```
<div ng-controller="simplecontroller" id="simplecontroller">
<a href="#">{{company.name}}</a>
</div>
app.controller('simplecontroller', function($scope) {
  $scope.company = {
    "name":"Comapny Name", "id":"1" 
  };
});
```

This might help - 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/index.htm

Comment: I am not familiar with laravel and angularjs together, but as you have mentioned, you can try it like - "name" : $company->name, "id" : $company->id...